# Check string contains only alphabets in C# and other allowed charaters are: ".", whitespace, ","

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string

How do I check that string does not contain only alphabets in C#, and other allowed charaters are: dot: ".", whitespace, and comma: ","

```
Regex regex = new Regex("Regex Pattern");
bool result = regex.IsMatch(string);
if(result)
 Messagebox.Show("String does not contain alphabets");
```

Examples:

ABC1 = false

ABC = true

ABC ABC = true

abc abc = true

A. B. ABC = true

The reason is because I have a field which contains people's names. Generally in these formats:

First

First Last

First Middle Last

F. M. Last

Title. F. M. Last

So, I want to validate those using regex.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Could you put what you tried in your question? Also, I don't think it's a good idea to tell someone their name is invalid because of special characters.

Comment: How does this fit your example? You want to make sure someone's name contains , and . but not any letters?

Comment: @Cyral I am so sorry, I meant only alphabets, space, dot and comma are allowed. No numeric digits and other special characters.

Comment: @Jerry I am so sorry, I meant only alphabets, space, dot and comma are allowed. No numeric digits and other special characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
var regex = new Regex(@"(?i)^[a-z.,\s]+$");
bool res =  regex.IsMatch(subject);
```

Comment: Forgot the upper-case letters.

Comment: @Anarion This is bull shit. Do you know what `(?i)` is doing? Dont downvote if you don't know. and your answer is plagiarizing too.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Worked perfectly. I have up-voted and selected as answer.

Comment: @Sriram Sakthivel My bad )